# Uncaught SyntaxError: Export 'import_react3' is not defined in module (at chunk-ALR5B6M7.js?v=aa4e0109:17143:3)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I have a project created with `create-react-app` with `Typescript`. And I am using `yarn 3.3.0` as the package manager.

Now I am trying to shift from `cra`s `webpack` to `vite`. I have bootstrapped a project with the `yarn create vite` command. And simply copy and paste the components from previous project to the new one.

When I run on the command line `yarn tsc` I am facing no error.

Also running `yarn dev` is okay in the terminal and the server starts successfully.

However, in the browser I am facing an weird error on the terminal which says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Export 'import_react3' is not defined in module (at chunk-ALR5B6M7.js?v=aa4e0109:17143:3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Apparently, since I am using Material UI I need to install `@emotion/react` and `@emotion/styled` as well.

Comment: Yeah the MUI docs are a bit misleading for Installation. It says default installation and emotion styles like you have it, and then right below, "With Styled Components..." one would assume separate from Emotion if you're not going to use it...BUT also required.

Comment: Issue is still not solving

Comment: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/examples/material-cra-styled-components-ts/package.json

This package setup in the examples seems to be saying that it is possible to not haave emotion while having styled components.

Also, this doc: https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/styled-engine/
Defines that you should resolve one module by another in the resolution.

Using vite, I haave not find how to yet...

Comment: Just found that if you use MUI icons, they rely on emotion: https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/

Comment: installing these packages resolved the issue

Answer (score 4):

This is for those who are using **MUI** install the following

**npm install --save @emotion/react**

**npm install --save @emotion/styled**

after installing **re-run** your project

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --force
```

this should fix the error

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using styled-components: https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/styled-components/

Vite not in docs but almost the same as Webpack if not using Yarn:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
export default defineConfig({

// Other stuff

resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@mui/styled-engine': '@mui/styled-engine-sc',
    },
},

})
```

Answer (score 0):

just delete the node module files and run npm install that will solve the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).